# alternative to GPS in location-based-services for iphone

Tags: iphone, location-based-service

Is there anyway i can decide that only with cell tower or wifi i can get location of the phone in iphone sdk. I don't want to use GPS at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use GPS? Wifi positioning can cause some strange results.

Comment: Android and other OS have the option of obtaining the location by means of GPS, CellId and Wifi at will. So i wanted to do something similar in iphone OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the [desiredAccuracy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18) to something lower.  The iphone will then use the most energy efficient method to calculate location, which normally won't be GPS.

However you cannot explictly tell it not to use GPS.